# Is it bad practice to include non-validating methods in a pydantic model?

Tags: python, validation, design-patterns, model, pydantic

I'm using pydantic 1.3 to validate models for an API I am writing.

**Is it common/good practice to include arbitrary methods in a class that inherits from `pydantic.BaseModel`?**

I need some helper methods associated with the objects and I am trying to decide whether I need a "handler" class. These models are being converted to JSON and sent to a restful service that I am also writing.

My model looks like this:

```py
class Foo(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    bar: int
    baz: int
```

Is it poor practice to do something like:

```py
class Foo(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    bar: int
    baz: int

    def add_one(self):
        self.bar += 1
```

It makes some sense to me, but I can't find an example of anyone doing this.

Comment: This is a great question. I have many use cases where I need to add some light functionality e.g. a method to construct the object from other data structures as well as validate it. Make a lot of sense to do in one class.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. We should probably document it.

The only problem comes when you have a field name which conflicts with the method, but that's not a problem if you know what your data looks like. Also, it's possible to over object orient your code, but you're a long way from that.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate pydantic's excellent documentation. Keep up  the good work.